# why left mouse select doesn't work

Tags: 3d-view

When i chose to have left mouse as my select function it should work yet it doesn't it just rotates the camera around the right mouse select works fine but why doesn't the left one?

Comment: I assume you already set the user preferences to have the selection on left click instead of right click?

Comment: im just an idiot i guess my some of my camera controls were bound incorrectly

Comment: You can add your own answer to this question, explaining what you had done wrong - in case someone else has the same problem in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do have this issue go to your user preferences and change your camera controls mine was interfering with the left click select so I set it back to the normal middle mouse click

Answer (score 0):

Minimize then maximize fixes it for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.